# Urysohn's Lemma, Stone-Weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

> Let $X$ be a compact space. Show that the following statements are equivalent:
>
> a) $X$ is homeomorphic to a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$
>
> b) There are functions $f_1,\dotso, f_n\in C(X)=\{f:X\to\mathbb{C}\quad\text{continuous}\}$, such that every linear combination of functions from the form
>
> $x\mapsto f_1(x)^{k_1}\cdot\dotso\cdot f_n(x)^{k_n}$ with $k_1,\dotso, k_n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ are dense in $C(X)$.

Hello,

I want to proof the implication a) "$\Rightarrow$" b).
For this task the hint is given, that we need the theorem of Stone-Weierstrass and Urysohn's Lemma.

To proof the first implication, I need a subalgebra $\mathcal{A}\subseteq C(X)$, which contains every linear combination of functions from the form above:

$x\mapsto f_1(x)^{k_1}\cdot\dotso\cdot f_n(x)^{k_n}$ with $k_1,\dotso, k_n\in\mathbb{N}_0$

How can I note this set $\mathcal{A}$?

$\mathcal{A}:=\{\sum_{i=1}^k f_{i_1}^{k_{i_1}}\cdot\dotso\cdot f_{i_n}^{k_{i_n}}, f_{i_1},\dotso, f_{i_n}\in C(X), k_{i_1},\dotso, k_{i_n}\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$

I am not sure, because the product of these functions can contain any function, and I do not really know, how to note it as a set.

After that I have to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a subalgebra and holds the three conditions of Stone-Weierstrass:

1) contains the constant functions

2) self-adjoint

3) seperates points

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For $a\implies b$, you can just use the polynomials on $n$ variables.

Comment: So $\mathcal{A}$ is simply $\mathcal{A}:=\{f_{i_1}^{k_{i_1}}\cdot\dotso\cdot f_{i_n}^{k_{i_n}}, f_{i_1},\dotso, f_{i_n}\in C(X), k_{i_1},\dotso, k_{i_n}\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$

Comment: Yes, except $f_i(\mathbf x)= x_i$

Comment: So constant functions are not in $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: When all exponents are zero, you get the constant functions

Comment: So you state, that this set does not contain the constant functions? But what if every exponent is zero except one, and this function is constant? Edit: Oh sorry, I missunderstood your comment. But what do you mean be $f_i(\rm x)=x_i$

Comment: So for $\Bbb R^2$, for example, we have $f_1(x_1,x_2)=x_1$ and $f_2(x_1,x_2)=x_2$

Comment: Ah, now I get it. You are talking about the projection. Can you give me a hint, where I need that $X$ is homeomorph to a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I guess it is needed, to show that $\mathcal{A}$ seperates points.

Answer (score 2):

For $a \implies b$, consider a subset $X \subseteq \Bbb R^n$, and the collection of functions
$$
f_1(\mathbf x) = x_1, f_2(\mathbf x) = x_2,\dots, f_n(\mathbf x) = x_{n}
$$
Note that $\mathcal A$ contains the constant function 
$$
g(x) = (f_1)^0(f_2)^0 \cdots (f_n)^0
$$
moreover, $\mathcal A$ separates points since for any two elements $\mathbf a = (a_1,\dots,a_n) \in X, \mathbf b = (b_1,\dots, b_n)\in X$, we can take the function
$$
g(\mathbf x) = (x_1-a_1)^2 + (x_2-a_2)^2 + \cdots + (x_n-a_n)^2
$$
which satisfies $g(\mathbf a) = 0$ and $g(\mathbf b) = \|\mathbf a - \mathbf b\|^2 > 0$.

If $X$ is *homeomorphic* to a subset of $\Bbb R^n$, all of this still works.  In particular, suppose that $h : X \to Y \subset \Bbb R^n$ is a homeomorphism.  Then, for $x \in X$, we can define
$$
\tilde f_i(x) = f_i (h(x))
$$
where $f_i$ are the "projections" as defined above.

---

For $b \implies a$, I think the idea is to define the map $h:X \to \Bbb R^n$ by
$$
h(x) = (f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x))
$$
and show that this map is a homeomorphism.  However, in the problem as written, the $f_i$ are complex-valued, which means that this isn't even a map into $\Bbb R^n$.